# Exact meaning of "Masters transcript"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was wondering if by "masters transcript" a transcript of all grades or just a certificate of examination or a confirmation of enrollment is meant? The text is about an application for an internship.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: We have no way of answering this question if you don't give us any context. Where is this text written?

Comment: I'm sorry, i thought it had a clear meaning to native speakers. "Master" relates to a masters degree at the university. The text is about an application for an internship.

Comment: The "application for an internship" is what I was fishing for... please add that to your question along with any other useful information...

Comment: It may also help to know what country you are referring to.  Different English-speaking countries use some of these expressions in different ways.

Comment: It is for an internship in an asian country. So it may not be the native language of the writer.

Comment: Why don' you just ask the institution that's asking for the master's transcript?

Comment: So, if you think that even the original writer of the expression may not be using it correctly, how do you expect US to know what he/she means??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of (probably most) U.S. universities this would mean a transcript from a Masters program; i.e., a list of courses taken and grades received with a calculated grade point average.

Comment: Glad it is helpful. I didn't want to put it into the answer, but in specifying a Masters transcript as opposed to an undergraduate transcript, this internship program in my view focuses correctly on recent capabilities. Many would just as soon be able to forget those "wandering" semesters or years back in undergrad days before a steady course was charted. ;)